# A simple square root calculator

Tags: python

Consider:

```
def square(x):
    """
    A simple function to calculate square of a number by addition.
    """
    sum_so_far = 0
    for counter in range(x):
        sum_so_far = sum_so_far + x
  return sum_so_far
```

The square root of 10 should be 3.16227, not 10.

Comment: The square of a number (x^2) is not equal to the square root of a number (x^0.5). So not sure, what you want to achieve here. Your code just sums up the number `x` for `x` times, which gives you basically x^2. Thus, your code should yield 100, which it in fact does.

Comment: The code seems to be a roundabout way of computing the *[square](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/square#Noun)* (avoiding multiplication).

Answer (score 0):

To get the square root of a number, have a peek at
[this article](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_math_sqrt.asp#:%7E:text=The%20math.,square%20root%20of%20a%20number.).
In short, use the following code:

```
import math
math.sqroot(number)
```